# How to escape * inside a regex?

Tags: java

I want to remove comments from a string.

When I tried with the regular expression

```
String ptrn = "/\\*.*\\*/";
```

while debugging it is showing string as `/\*.*\*/` and
my string is

```
String sg = "/* hello this is comment removing session by rejex */";
```

is not parsable. How can I remove or replace comments from a string?

Comment: It matches, is there an issue? https://ideone.com/OPKWcW

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are using is just fine for your case. You can use the `replaceAll(String, String)` method to achieve it.

```
String ptrn = "/\\*.*\\*/"; 
String sg = "/* hello this is comment removing session by rejex */";

String test = sg.replaceAll(ptrn, "");
System.out.println("Final string: "+ test);
```

The output in string test should be empty.

However, if you are looking for advanced comments removal from javadocs. Here is a [site](https://blog.ostermiller.org/finding-comments-in-source-code-using-regular-expressions/) which you could refer.

Comment: Thank you vikas i was thinking wrong.your explanation helped me.

Answer (score -1):

This is described in the Oracle documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html:

```
There are two ways to force a metacharacter to be treated as an ordinary character:

    precede the metacharacter with a backslash, or
    enclose it within \Q (which starts the quote) and \E (which ends it).
```

Comment: @Michael: Ah yes sorry, I answered the question from the title. The pattern in the text is correct.

Comment: Thank you Konrad Höffner it may help me